# Angular 2 view not updating after edit or delete operation executed on api

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular2-observables

I have delete operation on the same page that displays the list. When I execute delete the data in the api changes but it is not reflected in the list itself.

I tried a couple of things one was to pull the deleted object out of the observable array. That did not work and it is not what I want in my case because it will not reflect if other users have added or deleted "people" from the list.

The only thing that works now is to trigger api call once the delete operation is complete but it is not efficient.

In my opinion the correct approach will to trigger or refresh the subscription so that it goes back to the api gets the new data and adds the new ones or remove the one that does not exist in the database to the observable array.

Is there way to do it using observable and RxJs?

Thank you for help

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';

import {PeopleService} from '../shared/people.service';
import {People} from '../shared/people.model';
import {ToastService} from '../../../core/toast/toast.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-people-list',
  templateUrl: './people-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./people-list.component.css']
})
export class PeopleListComponent implements OnInit {

  peoples: Observable<People[]>;
  constructor(private peopleService: PeopleService,
  private toastService: ToastService) { }

  getPeoples() {
    this.peoples = this.peopleService.getPeoples()
  }

  deletePeople(people: People) {
    this.peopleService.deletePeople(people)
    .subscribe(
      () => {
        this.toastService.activate(' Deleted', 'People', 'danger');
      },
      (err) => console.log('Debug:deletefailed', err)
    );
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getPeoples();
  }

}
```

```html
<div>
  <h3>People List</h3>
  <hr/>
  <a href="" [routerLink]="['/peoples', 'new']"><button class="btn btn-primary">Add People</button></a>
  <table class="table table-hover">
    <thead class="thead-inverse">
      <tr>
        <th>Id</th>        
        <th>Number of People</th>
        <th>Modify</th>
        <th>Delete</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr *ngFor="let people of peoples | async">
        <th>{{people.id}}</th>
        <td>{{people.purchaseCount}}</td>
        <td><button href="#" [routerLink]="['/peopleDetail', people.id]" class="btn btn-sm btn-info">Edit/Detail</button></td>
        <td><button (click) = "deletePeople(people)" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger">Delete</button></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: ` peoples: Observable<People[]>;` why are you having your observable in your component?

Comment: The service returns an observable, it could also be just an array and not observable if I subscribe to the service within getPeople method.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly you have an observable service to delete and then want to refresh through another method that calls an observable. The issue here is an observable is async. The following code shows how I accomplished a similar task by using the the finally call to refresh the data. This in turn calls the service again to refresh data at the end of the first async call which would be completed.

```
delete(item: any) {

    if (confirm("Are you sure you wish to delete Lease ' " + item.title + " '")) {
        this.service.delete(item.leaseid)
            .finally(()=> {this.getLeases();})
            .subscribe(
            res => {
                this.alertService.success("Lease Has been Deleted");
            },
            err => {
                this.handleError(err);
            }
            )

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It makes no sense to have the peoples list as a stream if you want to operate on it.

```
export class PeopleListComponent implements OnInit {

  peoples: People[];
  constructor(private peopleService: PeopleService,
  private toastService: ToastService) { }

  deletePeople(people: People) {
    this.peopleService.deletePeople(people)
    .subscribe(
      () => {
        this.toastService.activate(' Deleted', 'People', 'danger');

       //***Remove people from the peoples list here**//

      },
      (err) => console.log('Debug:deletefailed', err)
    );
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getPeoples().subscribe(peoples => this.peoples = peoples);
  }

}
```

...

```
<tr *ngFor="let people of peoples">
```

And rebinding the response to peoples-list is not inefficient in any way since the view will have to update anyway.

The reason the view does not update simply because there isnt any new value being pushed to it

Comment: That is a way to solve it. And angular documentation also says the same thing. But for this specific instance, I cannot do that, because I also want to get any other objects that another user might have added.

Comment: When you're subscribing to the stream you get all values being pushed to that stream so this makes no difference from what i see in your code.

Comment: To be able to keep that list in sync you must fetch it again to maintain a consistent state. Not just for new values but also new deleted ones

Answer (score 0):

As you said you can always fetch fresh data from the database and update your list. But the only concern is you will have to give another request to API, which seems unnecessary.

Coming to your point

**it goes back to the api gets the new data and adds the new ones or remove the one that does not exist in the database to the observable array.**

Why don't you do getPeoples() within your delete subscription.

```
    deletePeople(people: People) {
        this.peopleService.deletePeople(people)
        .subscribe(
          (success) => {
            this.toastService.activate(' Deleted', 'People', 'danger');
            this.getPeoples();
          },
          (err) => console.log('Debug:deletefailed', err)
        );
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly the issue is not in Updating the `Component` itself? Becuase if it was Nicolas's answer would help... Although I would recommend not changing the pointer of the array as a best practice.
Instead of:

```
peoples: Observable<People[]>;    
getPeoples() {
    this.peoples = this.peopleService.getPeoples()
}
```

Do:

```
peoples: Array<People> = [];
getPeoples() {
    this.peoples.length = 0;
    this.peoples.push(...this.peopleService.getPeoples());
}
```

---

If you are looking for real-time updates cross user you could create a self-refreshing service- although this will increase API calls which will inevitably cost the user.

```
//refresh method:
private refreshData(): void {
    this.getPeople().subscribe(updated => {
        this.people.next(updated);
        this.subscribeToData();
    });
}
//timer method:
private subscribeToData(): void {
    Observable.timer(5000).first().subscribe(() => this.refreshData());
}
```

See detail explanation here: [Realtime Refresh](http://beyondscheme.com/2016/angular2-discussion-portal)

Also you should take a look at some frameworks that are built for this sort of thing such as [Fireloop.io](http://fireloop.io/).